# Macro to cut 10 cells down and transpose in a new sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose

Total novice with macros! I have a huge messy data sheet I need to transpose & freaking out.

I need to cut 10 cells in column A and transpose to the new sheet. I don't know how to get the macro to jump to 10 down after that (unless I can get it to delete those 10 rows?)

As an example:

Column A

**Person 1**
Address
Phone
Stuff
Hobbies
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
**Person 2**
Address
Phone
Stuff
Hobbies
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
**Person 3**
Address
Phone
Stuff
Hobbies
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah

into new sheet:

Column A        Column B Column C Column D Column E

**Person 1**    Address  Phone    Stuff    Hobbies  etc

This is the hopeless macro:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function TransposeMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:C10').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1:C10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D14').activate();
};
```

As I say, no idea what I'm doing! I give up - please can someone help?!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A)-1, 10), "♦", "♠")&A1:A,,9^9), "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image]